# Android Networkusage app,Error Parsing XML

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Ive been using the tutorials from developer.android.com I DID NOT modify any code in the "NetworkUsage" project ,My internet connection (fair) is limited to my android device so I debug using that but it gives me "Error parsing XML" instead of the regular webview display.Is this a general error and how can this be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the Manifest file and make it .NetworkActivity in the "android:name...." Insteadb of the com.example.android.NetworkActivity