# Trying to use the Android "Parsing XML Data" code doesn´t work: "Error parsing XML"

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I´ve got a problem with the code from this Android training-page: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
I downloaded the network usage.zip-file and didn´t change anything of the code. Unfortunately, it worked neither on my phone nor on my emulator.

After this, I googled the problem and found this thread here: [Android Networkusage app,Error Parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103307/android-networkusage-app-error-parsing-xml)
I tried to solve the problem with the solution provided by this thread, but unfortunately, it didn´t work and still shows me the error: "Error parsing XML"

I am pretty sure the error is in the Manifest-file because I looked at the settings of my phone and the app doesn´t have any permissions to use the Wifi or mobile data.

This is my "Android manifest file", the rest of my code is exactly as the code downloaded from the reference guide:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.networkusage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".NetworkActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="SettingsActivity" android:name=".SettingsActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who has the same issue: I found a way to make the app work. Actually, it worked without touching the manifest-file. However, in the "NetworkActivity.java"-file you need to change one line and paste in the URL directly (see below)

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=android&sort=newest%22");  
// *here instead of urls[0] you have to add the URL manually. I guess, it is not the most elegant solution, but it works ;)*
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
        }
    }
```